# Porque cuando muevo el archivo Ubicación.html a una carpetase quita todo el css que tenia y se queda como si no tuviera nada

Tags: html, css

[image: Este es el código que uso de css]
[image: Así se ve antes de mover el archivo Ubicacion.html]
[image: Así se ve luego de mover el archivo]

Ayuda con esto que no entiendo el porque me quita el css si no toco nada de ahí cuando muevo el archivo html

Comment: Cuando mueves un HTML de carpeta, también se debe modificar la dirección href del css

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! mas alla que no se entiende nada tu codigo en imagenes, si moviste el html, o modificas las rutas a los css, o moves los css tambien...

Answer (score 0):

sucede que hay dos tipos de dirección para rutas en html (estas rutas involucran tanto archivos css, como .js e imágenes) una dirección absoluta o ruta absoluta es aquella ruta que apunta directamente al archivo desde su ubicación en el dispositivo, ejemplo C:\mypc\Documentos\proyecto\index.html, una ruta relativa es aquella en donde el index a partir de su configuración, rellena lo que le falta a la ruta si no conoces la dirección exacta en el dispositivo, ejemplo http://localhost/index.html.

donde el http://localhost se encarga de colocar lo que falta de la ruta para poder ubicar el archivo.

entonces al tu mover tu archivo, la ruta absoluta que tenias se modifica porque ya no esta apuntando exactamente donde dices que esta.

en el caso que no se anteponga nada significa que estas en la misma carpeta, si mueves tu archivo a una carpeta entonces ya deberas subir un nivel de la carpeta con "../css/style.css" espero esto te ayude a entender mejor. Saludos